# Firebase .indexOn is not working as expected

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `content` node that I retrieve from a Firebase Realtime Database. 
I utilize `.orderByChild("time")` to get a Data Snapshot of the first 5 blog objects ordered by their earliest timestamps. I

am currently attempting to utilize `.indexOn : "time"` instead so that I do not have to utilize `.orderByChild("time")` as I am expecting for the blog objects to already be ordered by their timestamp by back-end when they are retrieved. (I am going to be working with a very large number of blog objects, so I want to utilize `.indexOn : "time"` in back-end instead of `orderByChild("time")` in front-end to increase efficiency). Currently, `.indexOn` does not work and the data isn't ordered by their time fields when it is retrieved.

query without `.indexOn`

```java
// this works fine
// startAt is utilized for saving last blog object retrieved to retrieve more data

query = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("content")
                .orderByChild("time")
                .startAt(nodeId)
                .limitToFirst(5);
```

query with .indexOn

```java
// this along with the Firebase rules below does not return the same result as above
// startAt is utilized for saving last blog object retrieved to retrieve more data

query = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("content")
                .startAt(nodeId)
                .limitToFirst(5);
```

Firebase rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
 ".read": true,
 ".write": true,
 "content" : {
      ".indexOn": "time"
  }
 }
}
```

JSON structure of data in Firebase :

```
"content" : {
"blog-0001" : {
  "content_id" : "blog-0001",
  "image" : "someimage",
  "time" : 13,
  "title" : "title1",
  "type" : "blog"
},
"blog-0002" : {
  "content_id" : "blog-0002",
  "image" : "someimage",
  "time" : 12,
  "title" : "title2",
  "type" : "blog"
},
"blog-0003" : {
  "content_id" : "blog-0003",
  "image" : "someimage",
  "time" : 11,
  "title" : "title3",
  "type" : "blog"
},
"blog-0004" : {
  "content_id" : "blog-0004",
  "image" : "someimage",
  "time" : 15,
  "title" : "title4",
  "type" : "blog"
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what `.indexOn` does, and how it related to `orderByChild("time")`.

To retrieve child nodes from `content` ordered by (and possibly also filtered on) `time`, you will always need to call `orderByChild("time")`.

If you define an index (using `".indexOn": "time"`) that ordering and filtering will be done on the server.

Without an index, all data under `content` will be downloaded to the client, and the ordering/filtering will be performed client side.

So `.indexOn` is not a replacement for `orderByChild`. Instead the two work hand in hand to perform efficient ordering and filtering of data.